# Mongoose function to return documents with two fields sum greater than a specified value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection and I want to return documents which their views + likes are greater than 100.
How can I do that using mongoose methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a standard query that you can look up in mongodb without a map-reduce over your full collection.

Here is a tutorial on how to do map-reduce queries with mongoose (looks like it actually uses the underlying node-mongodb-native driver): http://wmilesn.com/2011/07/code/how-to-map-reduce-with-mongoose-mongodb-express-node-js/

Mongoose has a trick up it's sleeve that can help you in this case, though. Simply create a [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) that updates a field with the combined score on each `save()` or `update()` operation. One advantage of this approach is that you can create an index on this combined field and have super fast lookups - much much faster than a map-reduce.

This [middleware page](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html), or [plugin page](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html) shows `schema.pre('save', ...)` which you can use to automatically update the `totals` field, each time you save the doc. You can then do a normal query on the totals field > 100.